# JS Form Fields Update Post-Submit

Tags: javascript, coordinates

I have a form that requires the current GPS `lat` and `lon`.  This is a mobile app so the best way is to update those form fields upon submission.  This is the JS I have to trigger that function before the form is submitted:

```
$('#form2').submit(function(){
  setpos();
  });


function foundLocation(pos) {
    document.getElementById("s_tlat").value = pos.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("s_tlon").value = pos.coords.longitude;
    }

function noLocation() {
    document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "Could not find your location";
    }

function setpos() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updateForm, noLocation);
    };

function updateForm(pos) {
    document.getElementById("s_tlat").value = pos.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("s_tlon").value = pos.coords.longitude;
//  alert("129");
    };
```

Upon several trials, I witness the form being updated, then the receiving `post` page receving the request and having no `parameters` at all.  This next line is a troubleshooting line that provides feedback on `params`, which shows the form is well designed and sending blanks for the fields that are in the form:

```
params: {"s_tname"=>"", "s_tlat"=>"", "s_tlon"=>"", "form2Submit"=>"Post New Item"}


<form action="/dorko" method="post" id="form2" name="post_tree">
    blah
    <input name="form2Submit" id="form2Submit" type="submit" value="Post New Item">
</form>
```

Upon entering the s_tname manually in the form, that gets sent just fine.  The `lat` and `lon` fields don't come through.  How can I get this to work?  What am I overlooking?

Comment: `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, so the form is submitting before it finishes.

Comment: But I am seeing the form updating before the page disappears.  Can I delay it for 5 seconds before this is submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous. You need to disable the default form submission, and submit the form explicitly from the callback after updating the fields.

```
$('#form2').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setpos();
});


function foundLocation(pos) {
  document.getElementById("s_tlat").value = pos.coords.latitude;
  document.getElementById("s_tlon").value = pos.coords.longitude;
}

function noLocation() {
  document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "Could not find your location";
}

function setpos(form) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updateForm, noLocation);
};

function updateForm(pos) {
  document.getElementById("s_tlat").value = pos.coords.latitude;
  document.getElementById("s_tlon").value = pos.coords.longitude;
  document.getElementById("form2").submit();
};
```